# Always on refresh per second on android wear 7.1.1

Tags: android, wear-os

Hi I'm trying to create a count down timer app on android wear and I would like the seconds portion of the timer to always tick no matter whether the app is in ambient mode or not.

I have managed to do this successfully using setAmbientEnabled(); with a CountDownTimer class timer running for an android version 8.0.0 (android wear). But unfortunately it does not seem to work well for android version 7.1.1; when it is in always on mode the timer is very inconsistent sometimes ticking every at random intervals and sometimes not ticking at all.

Is there a limit to the refresh rate for android 7.1.1 or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried using the complications API? https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/complications.html

Comment: What are you using to trigger the updates? An `AlarmManager` job, as recommended at https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html#update-content-in-ambient-mode ?

PS: I'm going to spare you the lecture about battery use and assume you've read the guidelines on that page.